# Weird hidden characters in exported XLIFF file

Tags: ios, xcode, internationalization, xliff

Whenever I try to *'Export For Internationalization'*, the exported file contains a weird hidden character, making it unparsable for XLIFF editors. The problem seemed to be in the original `.string` files, somehow the weird character was inserted in those files. I have since deleted the weird character but whenever I export it still sneaks into the `xliff` file. I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, restarting Xcode... none of that seems to work.

Is Xcode somehow using a cached version of the 'bad' `.strings` file containing the bad character?

## Using Xcode

If I try `Editor > Export For Localization`
I get:

`/usr/bin/xmllint exited with status 1`

[image: Xcode message after exporting for localization]

## Using Terminal

When I run it from Terminal like so:

`xcodebuild -exportLocalizations -localizationPath
/Users/Kymer/Downloads/Wolf  -project Wolf.xcodeproj -exportLanguage fr`

I get the following errors:

```
parser error : attributes construct error
parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag trans-unit
parser error : PCDATA invalid Char value 19
parser error : PCDATA invalid Char value 19
parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch
parser error : invalid character in attribute value
parser error : attributes construct error
parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag
parser error : PCDATA invalid Char value

/Uxcodebuild: error: /usr/bin/xmllint exited with status 1
```

In both cases the exported `xliff` file contains the weird hidden character upon inspection with Sublime Text:

[image: Screenshot of 'hidden' character in Sublime Text]

If I manually remove the bad characters the file is perfectly readable by xliff-editors but that's not a good long-term solution of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: when exporting to an XLIFF file Xcode doesn't look at your .string files, it is all generated from the project itself (i.e. it looks at all `NSLocalizedString` calls and your storyboards). Which makes sense. I found the weird hidden character in one of my code files. Removing it from the source file fixed the export issue.

### Easiest XLIFF workflow

I'll also mention this for future reference: the easiest way to add a **new language** to your project is to first use the command line:

`cd` to the your project and run:

```
xcodebuild -exportLocalizations -localizationPath <path>  -project <projectname>.xcodeproj -exportLanguage <language code>
```

That creates a new XLIFF file and will correctly set the target language in the file (source language will be your base language). A translator can now easily add all necessary translations. Afterwards you can import the translated XLIFF file back into Xcode (select target and `Editor > Import localizations`). Xcode will then generate all necessary .string files.

Updating **existing language**: If you add new UI elements and want to update an existing localization language, you can simply export an existing localization (select target and `Editor > Export for localization`). That XLIFF file will contain all previous translations together with the new strings. A translator simply has to fill in the 'blank' lines. There's no need to touch the `.string` files yourself, because managing that manually is a pain (especially with the crazy Storyboard ID's).